# How to set custom array to types.List in custom terraform provider for GO

Tags: go, terraform

I am working on a bug fix for a custom terraform provider written in Go. I am new in Terraform and even in the Go language, so pardon me if I make some mistakes.

I have this struct,

```
type resourceModel struct {
    Credentials types.List   `tfsdk:"credentials"`
}

type CredentialsModel struct {
    KeyCertificate KeyCertificateModel `tfsdk:"key_certificate"`
}

type KeyCertificateModel struct {
    Time types.String   `tfsdk:"time"`
}
```

Now during Read() state, I am getting some data from the API response. Now, to fill in that data this is something I am doing,

```
var state resourceModel

var credentials []CredentialsModel

for _, credential := range response.Credentials {
            m := CredentialsModel{
                    // logic to fill the above model
                    },
                },
            }
            credentials = append(credentials, m)
        }
state.Credentials, diags = types.ListValueFrom(ctx, state.Credentials.ElementType(ctx), credentials)
```

Here in diags, getting errors like,
`Mismatch between struct and object type: Struct defines fields not found in object: key_certificate. Object defines fields not found in struct: time.` Object type: types.ObjectType["time":basetypes.StringType]:

I am not sure if I have to use the `types.List` only in my `resourceModel` or do I have to use `credentials []CredentialsModel` instead as this error might be related to an object type mismatch. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never used Terraform but am an experienced Go programmer. It appears to me the error is saying that defining `KeyCertificateModel.Time` as a `types.String` is incompatible with the `tfsdk:"time"` annotation. Is a `tfsdk:"time"` meant to be serialized to/from a `types.String` rather than something like `time.Time` (from the Go stdlib)?

Comment: @KurtisRader So that time is coming as a string in API response, so made as string.

Comment: That the time is a string from an API response does not answer my question. Does the `tfsdk:"time"` struct annotation support converting a time as a string representation? Given the error you are seeing I would conclude that is not true. That is, I suspect the struct member has to be something like `types.Time`. Of course, given that your question is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I am only guessing about the nature of the problem.